# git | local repo and remote repo

Tags: git, local

Beginner...
I have a local repo which files I use for a website on a remote server.
These files I also keep as a remote repo on Bitbucket.
The local saved files I changed and made huge errors on so I downloaded from the website server the known working files and saved in my local files.

I'm now trying to push these known working files to Bitbucket but I'm having issues and error messages as 'refusing to merge unrelated histories' and 'Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
its remote counterpart'.

As I state at the start I'm a beginner and know I may not of done things in the correct procedure but I'm learning. I'm not necessarily after the 'answer' but would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Which git commands did you run and what do you mean by "I downloaded from the server and saved locally"? Was this done with git or?

Comment: To download the files from the server which host the website  I used filezilla and right clicked to download and overwrote my local files which I had errors on. I now want to push these known working files to Bitbucket but keep getting the errors mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll my best to provide a proper answer. When you want to push commits to the server you have to make sure that both the remote and local repositories have the same set of commits.

If the remote has a few commits more than your local branch, then you will get errors when you try to push your files to the remote. In such cases, you need to perform a fast-forward by either pulling or re-basing the extra commits.

From the errors that you have mentioned, I believe the following might fix the errors. I'm assuming you are committing files to the `master` branch.

`git fetch origin master`

Before you go to the next step, please make sure that your working directory is clean (i.e there are no untracted or modified files). If not, you can either commit the changes or [stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash) them.

`git rebase origin/master`

Now, when you perform a `rebase` you may get merge-conflicts. If you do get merge-conflicts you'll have to resolve them. On the other hand if you don't get any merge-conflicts you can proceed to push the files to remote.

If however you get merge-conflicts please try the following -

`git status`

This will present you with all the files that have merge-conflicts. You'll have to go to all the files and resolve the conflicts. After you are done with that, you have to add all the files that you had changed while fixing the merge-conflicts.

`git add -A`

And then you can continue with the rebase -

`git rebase --continue`

Hopefully, after going through these steps you should be able to push your files to remote. Please do note that there are other ways to resolve merge-conflicts. I use the method mentioned above.

Comment: I got to the git rebase --continue and got this back $ git rebase --continue
No rebase in progress. I tried to push after and got the same errors

Comment: Also tried ...$ git rebase origin
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'origin'

Comment: oh I see, did you get merge-conflicts? If not, then you don't have to use `rebase --continue`

Comment: after running git status...nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: $ git rebase continue
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'continue

Comment: hmm, okay. Can you please try the following again - 

`git fetch origin master`

`git rebase origin/master`

You should see something like - 'First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...' on your terminal. Do you see this on your terminal? or do you see something else? 

Also, did you create any commits after you overwrote the files?

Comment: If nothing works out, you can try `git push -f origin master` as a last resort which will force push the files to the remote. However, this is not the right thing to do because this will overwrite files on your remote and you may lose some of the files on remote permanently.

Comment: $ git fetch origin master
From https://bitbucket.org/frogo123/magento-store
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

Comment: Additionally, I did create commits after I overwrote the files